# Extracting and testing an express-validator function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

I'd like to test my implementation of `express-validator` rules in my middleware. I understand that I shouldn't test 3rd party code, but in my (perhaps flawed) view, I'm testing my implementation rather than their code.

A cut down version would usually look like this:

```
// routes.js
router.post('/example',
[
  body('email')
    .isString()
    .withMessage('Invalid characters, please use letters and numbers only'))
],
//// To be replaced by:
// validateLogin(),
controller.exampleFn());
```

but I need to be able to extract it for testing, which I do by [running the validations imperatively:](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/running-imperatively)

```
// validation.js

// parallel processing
const validate = validations => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    await Promise.all(validations.map(validation => validation.run(req)));

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
      return next();
    }

    const error = new Error();
    error.message = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'? 'Validation Failed':'Error';

    error.statusCode = !errors.isEmpty()? 422:500;
    error.errors = errors.array({onlyFirstError: true});
    next(error);
    return error;
  };
};

const validateLogin = () => {
  const exampleValidationRules = [
    body('email')
      .isString()
      .withMessage('Invalid characters, please use letters and numbers only')
  ];
  return validation(exampleValidationRules);
}

module.exports = {
  validateLogin
};
```

I can then call the middleware in my routes, and in my test files.

For example:

```
// auth.test.js
describe('Unit Tests', () => {
  it('should return 422 if email validation fails', async() => {
    const wrongEmailReq = { body: {email: 'nic@hotmail.com'} };
    const notStringReq = { body: {email:1} };
    const res = {
      statusCode: 500,
      status: (code) => {this.statusCode = code; return this},
    };

    // Function to be tested  
    const validationFn = validateLogin();

    const wrongEmail = await validationFn(wrongEmailReq, res, ()=>{});
    const notString = await validationFn(notStringReq, res, ()=>{});

    expect(wrongEmail.statusCode).to.be.equal(422);
    expect(wrongEmail.errors[0].param).to.be.equal('email');

    expect(notString.statusCode).to.be.equal(422);
    expect(notString.errors[0].param).to.be.equal('email');

    return;
});
```

I'm just slightly confused about how I'd test the 'success' case. `validationFn` returns `next()` if successful. But that would just be `undefined`.

Should I just test `expect(correct.statusCode).to.be.undefined;`? That doesn't seem specific enough.

Also, is there actually any advantage to unit testing this function over using `http-chai` to run the requests? I thought perhaps it was more lightweight, but unsure.

Comment: You could pass a spy function as the next parameter (instead of `()=>{}`) and then check with which argument it is called (`undefined` in case of no error, `some error` in case of an error)

Comment: Oh ok, nice. I've not used spy functions before so I'll take a look at how they work, thanks!